# Python warning: Expected Collection.Iterable, got 'int' instead

Tags: python

I am a Python newbie :)

Given this code:

```
    some_list_len = len(some_list)
    for i in some_list_len :
        print some_list[i]
```

Why do I get the warning in subject?
 How can I overcome that?

Best regards!

Comment: `len(some_list)` returns an integer. So you're trying to for loop over an integer, which is not a valid operation. What is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: @Proyag Thanks. Please see edited post

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type of `some_list_len` in your code is Int, so you get the warning.

If you want to iterate `some_list_len`, you can implement by this:

```py
    some_list_len = len(some_list)
    for i in range(some_list_len) :
        print some_list[i]
```

or directly use this:

```py
    for element in some_list :
        ···
```

and if you want to use indices, you can use `enumerate`:

```py
    for i, element in enumerate(some_list) :
        ···
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case `some_list_len` is the actual length of the list `some_list`. Threfore, this is just an integer, and you cannot iterate an integer.

I imagine you want to use `range()` as in:

```
some_list_len = len(some_list)
for i in range(0, some_list_len):
    print i
```

This will iterate from 0 (or any other value you specify) to the length of your list.

Comment: You should add that it is not required in Python. OP can simply do `for something in some_list: print something`